# No sys/sendfile.h on Cygwin?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cygwin

I'm trying to compile some C code on Cygwin which needs the sendfile.h. When I try to compile, it gives me

```
fatal error: sys/sendfile.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

How do I solve this? Will I have to move to a linux platform? I have gcc4.5 installed on Cygwin.

Comment: `sendfile` is specific to Linux. Cygwin is not Linux. Cygwin is a Posix implementation. Your code is patently not pure Posix code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comment mentioned, `sendfile` is not POSIX, however, from the man page of
[sendfile(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile)

> sendfile() copies data between one file descriptor and another. 
>   Because this copying is done within the kernel, sendfile() is more
>   efficient than the combination of read(2) and write(2), which would
>   require transferring data to and from user space.

Which means it's basically a `read()` followed by a `write()`, so it would be relatively easy to implement it yourself.

Comment: So is there a difference between sendfile() and send()? Aren't they both use kernel space as opposed to read() and write()? Thanks

Comment: yes, but sendfile() combines the read() and write() in one call, so it's more efficient that a read() followed by a write() (or send()) because that would require data to be transferred to userspace.

Comment: Any ideas how to reimplement it in Cygwin?

Comment: @samsamara the difference is efficiency. sendfile is a single system call, no data transfer between kernel and user space. Otherwise it is equivalent to a combination of read and write.

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
```

and
rewrite

```
sendfile(write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
```

to

```
read(read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
write(write_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
```

and it works fine.
Thanks.